# Classe aninhada em Java

Tags: java, classes

Eu preciso ter classes aninhadas em Java. Por que a seguinte implementação não funciona?

```
public class A{
    private class B{
        public B(){
            System.out.println("class B");
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
         A a = new A();
         B b = new B();
    }
}
```

Na linha que eu tento instanciar a inner class B, o seguinte erro ocorre:

> No enclosing instance of type A is accessible

Comment: Olá rogger, bem vindo ao [pt.so], poderia nos dar mais detalhes? Como por exemplo qual erro ocorre? Em qual linha?

Comment: na linha que eu tento instanciar a inner class B, o seguinte erro ocorre: No enclosing instance of type A is accessible.

Comment: A classe B e privada, logo so pode ser instanciada a partir de uma instacia da classe A.

Comment: @LucasVirgili Na verdade não é por ser "privada", é por `B` ser um membro de `A`; mesmo que `B` não fosse privado, este código só funcionaria se `main` não fosse estático.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Não dá para instanciar da forma direta como você fez. É necessário uma referência para a classe mãe por isto antes precisa criar uma instância para dela e nesta instância acessar a classe interna. Veja este exemplo que peguei de um [tutorial sobre classes internas](http://www.oursland.net/tutorials/java/innerclasses/):

```
public class InnerClassTest {
    public void foo() {
        System.out.println("Outer class");
    }

    public class ReallyInner {
        public void foo() {
            System.out.println("Inner class");
        }

        public void test() {
            this.foo();
            InnerClassTest.this.foo();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        InnerClassTest o = new InnerClassTest();
        InnerClassTest.ReallyInner i = o.new ReallyInner();
        i.test();
    }
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Class/InnerClass.java).

Comment: Na verdade não tem a ver com a visibilidade de `B` mas sim o fato de ele ser um membro não estático de `A`, de modo que ele só pode ser acessado a partir de uma instância de `A`. Para ser acessível sem uma instância de `A`, `B` precisaria ser uma membro estático. Veja minha resposta. cc @rogger.

Comment: O @Caffé tem razão. Tanto o método main quanto a classe privada B estão dentro da mesma classe, a classe A, logo não existe problema de visibilidade da inner class. Um simples `B b = a.new B();` resolve o problema do AP, ou mudar a classe B para static.

Comment: Bacana editar para retirar a nota sobre o "private". Falta ainda responder a pergunta "Por que?".

Comment: Já estava dito só que estava com outras palavras

Answer (score 5):

O seu código não funciona porque você está tentando acessar um membro não estático de `A` (a classe aninhada `B`) a partir de um método estático (`static main`); e você só pode acessar membros não estáticos de uma classe a partir de uma instância da classe.

Então para seu código funcionar, você tem 3 opções:

Instanciar `B` a partir de uma instância de `A`:

```
public class A{
    private class B{
        public B(){
            System.out.println("class B");
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
         A a = new A();
         B b = a.new B(); // instância de B a partir de uma instância de A
    }
}
```

Mudar o método `main` para não estático, pois se ele for um método de instância, tem acesso a membros não estáticos da sua classe:

```
public class A{
     private class B{
        public B(){
            System.out.println("class B");
        }
    }
    // instância de B a partir de um método não estático de A    
    public void doSomething(String[] args){ 
        // A a = new A();
         B b = new B();
    }
}
```

Ou declarar `B` como classe estática, assim ele fica acessível a partir membros estáticos (no caso, o método `main`).

```
public class A{
     // B declarado como classe estática
     private static class B{
        public B(){
            System.out.println("class B");
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
         A a = new A();
         B b = new B();
    }
}
```

**Update:** No segundo exemplo mudei o nome do método para não ser confundido como método de entrada de uma main class Java, pois para tal ele precisaria ser estático. Este código tem apenas o papel didático sobre classes aninhadas.

Comment: Não gostei da sua segunda opção. Você fez uma aberração com o método main, não tem como você rodar esse código. O método main DEVE ser estático, não existe outra opção.

Comment: Não viaja, @Math. `A a = new A(); a.main(new String[] { "parametro 1" });`. Eis o código rodando. Onde está a aberração? Não foi perguntado "como rodar esse código como método de entrada em uma main class de um JAR ou por linha de comando usando Java". A dúvida é sobre classes aninhadas.

Comment: @Math Agora que você entendeu, desdonwvota isso aí e dá o meu +1 :D

Comment: Sim, entendi que você pode fazer um método com o nome de main sem ele ser "O" método main, mas não seria melhor você deixar claro isso na sua resposta? Outra coisa, depois de 15 min que o voto foi dado ele fica bloqueado, seja ele positivo ou negativo, para eu poder mudar meu voto você precisava editar qualquer coisa na sua publicação, e eu ficaria muito feliz se a edição fosse mudando o nome do método main que não é tão main assim :)