# Qual a diferença entre classe interna, classe aninhada e classe anônima?

Tags: java, orientação-a-objetos

Frequentemente leio a respeito desses 3 tipos de classes quando estou pesquisando algo sobre java, mas a verdade é que muitas vezes causa uma certa confusão sobre o que cada uma delas realmente é e se tem alguma diferença entre si.

O que são classes internas, aninhadas e anônimas? Pode-se definir que são a mesma coisa entre si ou são coisas diferentes?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Segundo [J Steven Perry](https://www.linkedin.com/in/jstevenperry1) da Makoto Consulting Group 
**Classe aninhada**
são todas as classes que estão dentro de outra classe.

**Exemplo:**

```
public class calculadora {


public class soma{/* código */ }

}
```

Este tipo de classe é utilizado para manipular dados de processamento interno, mas é limitada pela classe que precisa dela.
Geralmente se usa este tipo de classe quando ambas as classes estão **Intimamente ligadas**. A classe aninhada terá acesso aos dados primitivos declarados pela classe que a chamou.
**Nota**: é um tipo de classe interna.

> Como a classe aninhada tem um escopo, ela está limitada pelas regras
>   do escopo. Por exemplo, uma variável de membro pode ser acessada
>   apenas por uma instância da classe (um objeto). O mesmo é verdade para
>   uma classe aninhada. Suponha que você tenha o seguinte relacionamento
>   entre um Manager e uma classe aninhada denominada DirectReports, que é
>   uma coleção dos Employees que se reportam a esse Manager:
>
> ```
> public class Manager extends Employee {  
>
>     private DirectReports directReports; 
>
>     public Manager() {
>         this.directReports = new DirectReports();  
>     }
>
>     ...  
>
>     private class DirectReports {  . . .  } 
> }
> ```
>
> Assim como cada objeto Manager representa um único ser humano, o
>   objeto DirectReports representa uma coleção de pessoas reais
>   (funcionários) que se reportam a um gerente (Manager). O DirectReports
>   será diferente de um Manager para outro. Nesse caso, faz sentido que
>   ele faça referência à classe aninhada DirectReports no contexto da
>   instância de Manager que a encerra, assim ela foi feita private.

Da mesma forma eu usei no primeiro exemplo... imagine a classe calculadora:

```
public class Calculadora extends Calculos{
   private  Soma soma;

   public Calculadora(){
      this.soma = New Soma();
   }

   public class Soma {}
}
```

A soma é um conjunto de cálculos que eu chamei internamente e mostrei, e como está *private* será acessada somente pela classe de contexto, no caso, a classe Calculadora.

E se eu quiser utilizar pública?

Exemplo respondido pelo @Maniero em outro [post do site](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/37515/classe-aninhada-em-java).

Não da pra receber diretamente igual é como privado:

> É necessário uma referência para a classe mãe por isto antes precisa
>   criar uma instância para dela e nesta instância acessar a classe
>   interna. Veja este exemplo que peguei de um tutorial sobre classes
>   internas:
>
> ```
> public class InnerClassTest {
>     public void foo() {
>         System.out.println("Outer class");
>     }
>
>     public class ReallyInner {
>         public void foo() {
>             System.out.println("Inner class");
>         }
>
>         public void test() {
>             this.foo();
>             InnerClassTest.this.foo();
>         }
>     }
>
>     public static void main(String[] args) {
>         InnerClassTest o = new InnerClassTest();
>         InnerClassTest.ReallyInner i = o.new ReallyInner();
>         i.test();
>     }
> }
> ```

**Classes Internas:**

<kbd>[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]</kbd>

*Imagem disponível nas referências*

Vamos uma por uma, a primeira já foi definida,**classes aninhadas**, que é uma classe interna e a mais comum dentre todas.

**Classe interna Estática**

> Uma classe estática não tem acesso aos membros da instância da classe
>   encapsulada, somente os membros estáticos, tem a mesma visibilidade de
>   uma classe externa.

```
public class Calculadora {

  public static class Soma{
    int a = 1;
    int b = 2;
  }
}
```

Neste exemplo a classe soma tem dois atributos inteiros, a e b:

- `a` sempre será 1
- `b` sempre será 2

pois são estáticos... não se alterarão.

**Classes internas de métodos**

Métodos também tem classes? Sim!

```
protected  void Calcular(){

    class Calculo{
        private int soma;

        public void setSoma(int soma) {
            this.soma = soma;
        }

        public int getSoma() {
            return soma;
        }
    }
}
```

Neste caso a classe estará definida pelo escopo do método, não pode ser declarada como estática, e, a classe apenas poderá ser acessada por outras classes deste método.

**Classe anônima**

Toda classe que não é declara explicitamente mas esta sendo chamada no código, representa o comportamento de uma classe ou de uma interface.

```
 protected  void Calcular(){
          int a,b;
          Calculo calculo = new Calculo;
          calculo.somar({
public void somei(){

}
});// parece o click listener

}
```

Partindo do exemplo que não existe necessariamente uma classe para o método somar, mas , sem declaração ela esta lá , ou seja **classes anônimas** são classes internas que funciona como uma subclasse do tipo do objeto, não de onde esta sendo referenciado (no caso objeto do tipo somar).

> Pode-se definir que são a mesma coisa entre si?

Encerrando, Classe aninhada é um tipo de classe interna, que usamos comumente, enquanto as anônimas nem tanto, já que funciona como uma sub chamada no método já instanciado, não é comum, e algumas vezes vai dificultar a leitura do código, já que a classe poderia estar declarada antes...
Então em geral classes aninhadas e anônimas são classes internas... e classe interna é todas aquelas que estão sendo chamadas dentro de alguma outra classe, método, ou anonimamente(sem declaração) em uma chamada da classe "pai" com um método em questão.

**Referências:**

[Classe aninhadas](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/br/java/tutorials/j-introtojava2/section7.html)

[Classes internas](http://www.inf.ufes.br/~vitorsouza/wp-content/uploads/java-br-curso-basico-novo-slides08.pdf)

[Classes internas](http://javafree.uol.com.br/artigo/6954/Cap-8-Classes-internas.html)

[Classes internas](http://www.devmedia.com.br/aprendendo-sobre-classes-internas/15581)

[Classe anônima](https://coisasdesoftware.wordpress.com/2013/04/07/classes-anonimas/)

[Classe interna anônima](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html)

Comment: Ótima resposta! :)