# Como mudar o foco entre tabs num JTabbedPane?

Tags: java, swing

Eu estou tentando fazer a seguinte rotina. Em minha tela "principal", eu possuo um `JTabbedPane` com duas abas, no qual o foco fica na primeira aba.

Eu preciso abrir um `JInernalFrame` e, ao fecha-lo, fazer com que o foco vá para a segunda aba do meu `JTabbedPane`. Porém, da maneira que eu tentei fazer me retorna uma `NullPointerException` e não dá o foco para aba 02.

Eu fiz um exemplo bem simples, mais que ilustra bem o que eu estou tentando fazer:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JDesktopPane;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JInternalFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTabbedPane;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class TelaPrincipal extends JFrame {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Runnable startApp = () -> {
            TelaPrincipal fc = new TelaPrincipal();
            fc.setVisible(true);
        };

        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(startApp);
    }

    private JTabbedPane jTabbedPane = new JTabbedPane();
    private JButton button = new JButton("Click");
    private JDesktopPane jdp = new JDesktopPane();

    public TelaPrincipal() {
        add(montaTela());
        setSize(700, 400);
        action();
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    private JPanel montaTela() {
        JPanel painel = new JPanel();
        painel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        jTabbedPane.add("Aba 01", new JLabel("→ Aba 01"));
        jTabbedPane.add("Aba 02", new JLabel("→ Aba 02"));
        jTabbedPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500, 150));

        painel.add(jTabbedPane, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        painel.add(jdp, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        painel.add(button, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        return painel;
    }

    public JTabbedPane getjTabbedPane() {
        return jTabbedPane;
    }

    private void action() {
        button.addActionListener(e -> {
            Tela tela = new Tela();
            jdp.add(tela);
            tela.setVisible(true);
        });
    }

    // ---------------------------------------------
    class Tela extends JInternalFrame {

        private JButton close = new JButton("Close");

        public Tela() {
            setTitle("Tela interna");
            add(montaTela());
            setSize(300, 100);
            actionClose();
            setVisible(true);
            setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        }

        private JPanel montaTela() {
            JPanel painel = new JPanel();
            painel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
            painel.add(new JLabel("Apenas para demonstrar .."), BorderLayout.NORTH);
            painel.add(close, BorderLayout.CENTER);
            return painel;
        }

        private void actionClose() {
            close.addActionListener(e -> {
                dispose();
                TelaPrincipal tlp = new TelaPrincipal();
                //tlp.getjTabbedPane().getTabComponentAt(1).getParent().requestFocus();
                tlp.getjTabbedPane().getTabComponentAt(1).requestFocus();
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Não faz muito sentido isso. Se quer que o foco vá para a tab seguinte, altere a seleção para ela. Dessa forma ai nunca vai funcionar.

Comment: @Articuno Talvez não faça sentido por ser um exemplo bem simples, mais, a questão de mudar de abas, é que em uma eu vou ter um tabela de parcelas e na outra de pagamentos, quando pagar uma parcela pela tela que abre, ele vai para a aba dos pagamentos. Eu implementei as classes conforme o exemplo, mais não deu certo.

Comment: Veja a resposta abaixo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O que você está tentando fazer não é alterar foco, é alterar seleção, são coisas diferentes, se não for isso e realmente for o que foi explicado na pergunta, não faz muito sentido.

Supondo que seja realmente alterar a tab selecionada, basta modificar conforme abaixo, utilizando o método [`setSelectedIndex()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javax/swing/JTabbedPane.html#setSelectedIndex-int-), já que se trata de uma [innerclass](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/192104/28595):

```
private void actionClose() {
    close.addActionListener(e -> {
        dispose();
        getjTabbedPane().setSelectedIndex(1);
    });
}
```

Testando:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Apenas advertindo que você estava criando uma nova instancia da janela principal, o que era outro erro. Uma vez que a classe é interna, você pode acessar os métodos e atributos diretamente. Se a classe for criada a parte, você vai precisar passar a instancia da tela principal entre o as `JInternalFrame`.