# Declaração de classes em Java

Tags: java, orientação-a-objetos, classes

Posso declarar mais de uma classe no mesmo arquivo em Java, e caso isto seja possível, é a forma mais correta de se programar nesta linguagem?

Comment: Relacionada:[Qual a diferença entre classe interna, classe aninhada e classe anônima?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/192104/qual-a-diferença-entre-classe-interna-classe-aninhada-e-classe-anônima)

Comment: Recomendo a leitura deste topico linkado.

Comment: Alguma das respostas resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitar uma delas? Veja o [tour] como fazer isso, se ainda não o fez. Você ajudaria a comunidade identificando qual foi a melhor solução para você. Pode aceitar apenas uma delas. Mas pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo

Answer (score 4):

Sim, é perfeitamente possível e faz sentido se as classes são muito relacionadas, até porque só uma das classes pode ser pública.

Nesse tipo de coisa não tem correto sem ver o contexto. Há quem recomende colocar uma classe por arquivo, e até é uma boa recomendação, mas não que deva ser seguida sempre. Digamos que não é comum, mas pode quando as outras classes não são tão importantes.

Comment: Apenas um exemplo, a api do google maps retorna um json que pode ser convertido para um objeto java, alguns dos objetos filhos (não sei se esse é o termo adequado) são muito simples (2 ou 3 campos) e podem ser colocados juntos a uma outra classe para evitar 20 e poucos arquivos só pra converter o retorno da api

Answer (score 1):

Sim é possível, porém deve ser usado com cuidado, principalmente se pensarmos na manutenção disso, imagine que a medida que o projeto cresce essas classes podem mudar seu escopo e na prática, dificilmente você (ou outro programador da equipe) irá se lembrar de modificar essa estrutura.

Sugiro a leitura [desse artigo](https://www.devmedia.com.br/entendendo-coesao-e-acoplamento/18538) sobre coesão e acoplamento, isso vai te ajudar na hora de modelar suas classes.

Então você pode usar, porém deve analisar se realmente isso faz sentindo para seu projeto.