# error: non-static variable this cannot be referenced from a static context / Java 8

Tags: java, syntax-error, static, uri

Estou fazendo um exercicio do URI (online judge) mas está apresentando "compilation error" devido ao erro:

Main.java:8: error: non-static variable this cannot be referenced from a static context
InterfaceTexto i = new InterfaceTexto();
^
1 error

Segue o código:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.IOException;

public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
    {
        InterfaceTexto i = new InterfaceTexto();
        i.executar();
    }
class InterfaceTexto
{
    private Scanner entrada;
    private Fibonacci fibonacci;
    private int n;
    private int t;

    public InterfaceTexto()
    {
        entrada = new Scanner(System.in);
        fibonacci = new Fibonacci();
    }
    
    public void executar()
    {
        t = entrada.nextInt();
        
        for(int i = 0; i < t; i++)
        {
            fibonacci();           
        }
    }
    
    public void fibonacci()
    {
        n = entrada.nextInt();
        System.out.printf("Fib(%d) = %d\n", n, fibonacci.numeroFibonacci(n)); 
    }
}
class Fibonacci
{
    private int[] fib;
    private int n;
    private static final int TAM = 61;

    public Fibonacci()
    {
        fib = new int[TAM];

        fib[0] = 0;
        fib[1] = 1;

        for (int i = 2; i < TAM; i++)
            fib[i] = fib[i-1] + fib[i-2];
    }

    public int numeroFibonacci(int n)
    {
        int numero = fib[n];

        return numero;
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

### Solução rápida

Faltou a chave para fechar a classe Main.

```java
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        InterfaceTexto i = new InterfaceTexto();
        i.executar();
    }
// aqui
}
    class InterfaceTexto
    {
        ...
    }
```

### Entendendo o problema

- Quando você não fechou a chave da classe `Main`, InterfaceTexto se tornou uma classe interna.
- Para instanciar a classe interna a partir de um método (não estático) da classe ficaria assim:

```java
    public void anyMethod() {
        InterfaceTexto i = new InterfaceTexto();
    }
```

Mas quando você tentou instanciar a partir do método `main`, você encontrou esse erro:

`non-static variable this cannot be referenced from a static context`

O que o erro está dizendo é:

- variáveis não estáticas (se referindo a classe `InterfaceTexto`) não podem ser referenciadas no contexto estático.
- o contexto estático é porque você está dentro do método `main`
- se o problema envolvesse declarar a classe interna como estática, então você poderia instanciar um objeto dentro de main como você fez! Mas não acredito que seja esse o melhor caminho.

```java
static class InterfaceTexto {
...
}
```

### Referências para leitura

Veja aqui uma [boa leitura sobre classes internas/aninhadas aqui do SOpt](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/192104/qual-a-diferen%C3%A7a-entre-classe-interna-classe-aninhada-e-classe-an%C3%B4nima)